# What exactly is "Browser" in Chrome's task manager, if it's not an open tab, and where is the traffic coming from?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser

I'm having problems loading some webpages on a slow connection on Chrome, and opened its Task Manager and saw that the "Browser" task is using up all the bandwidth to download something, but I don't know what it is downloading or how to stop it.

[image]

This is very inconvenient in slow speed connections such as 128 kilobits/second. Whenever there is download traffic in "Browser", it stalls the page loads of several tabs as this task is using up all the available bandwidth.

What is the source of "Browser" and its download activity? Extensions have their own tasks on the list but no download activity is coming from there. I also have no file downloads running in the background.

Comment: Maybe it's Chrome auto-update feature?

Comment: The Browser is Google Chrome Program and you need it for internet you cannot kill its task

Comment: Puzzling: I have looked at this task in both Ubuntu and Win10, and I saw occasional CPU use, but no network activity. Maybe you should try an alternative browser, such as Firefox or Opera: there are [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) versions of both.